# what's the meaning of "put someone under the dress"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> they are doing by the book and **we're putting them under the dress**

From the TV series 'Suits' Season1, Pilot episode.

What does "put someone under the dress" mean here?

I googled it but I couldn't find any useful website or information.

Answer (score 21):

The phrase they used isn't "under the dress", but "under **duress**". [*Duress*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duress) means "force or threats used to make someone do something", and it's usually used with "under" as in someone being made to do something *under duress*.  So the character is saying "We are threatening them in order to make them do what we want."

The line can be found in the script [here](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=suits&episode=s01e01).

Comment: I was *very* confused because that's not a phrase I had ever heard. But *under duress* makes a *lot* more sense.